# Program structure in long running data processing python script

Tags: python, language-agnostic, refactoring, maintainability

For my current job I am writing some long-running (think hours to days) scripts that do CPU intensive data-processing.  The program flow is very simple - it proceeds into the main loop, completes the main loop, saves output and terminates:  The basic structure of my programs tends to be like so:

```
<import statements>
<constant declarations>

<misc function declarations>

def main():
   for blah in blahs():
      <lots of local variables>
      <lots of tightly coupled computation>

      for something in somethings():
          <lots more local variables>
          <lots more computation>

   <etc., etc.>

   <save results>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This gets unmanageable quickly, so I want to refactor it into something more manageable.  I want to make this more maintainable, without sacrificing execution speed.

Each chuck of code relies on a large number of variables however, so refactoring parts of the computation out to functions would make parameters list grow out of hand very quickly. Should I put this sort of code into a python class, and change the local variables into class variables?  It doesn't make a great deal of sense tp me conceptually to turn the program into a class, as the class would never be reused, and only one instance would ever be created per instance.

What is the best practice structure for this kind of program? I am using python but the question is relatively language-agnostic, assuming a modern object-oriented language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if your program is going to be running for hours/days then the overhead of switching to using classes/methods instead of putting everything in a giant main is pretty much non-existent.

Additionally, refactoring (even if it does involve passing a lot of variables) should help you improve speed in the long run. Profiling an application which is designed well is much easier because you can pin-point the slow parts and optimize there. Maybe a new library comes along that's highly optimized for your calculations... a well designed program will let you plug it in and test right away. Or perhaps you decide to write a C Module extension to improve the speed of a subset of your calculations, a well designed application will make that easy too.

It's hard to give concrete advice without seeing `<lots of tightly coupled computation>` and `<lots more computation>`. But, I would start with making every `for` block it's own method and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Not too clean, but works well in little projects...

You can start using modules as if they were singleton instances, and create real classes only when you feel the complexity of the module or the computation justifies them.

If you do that, you would want to use "import module" and not "from module import stuff" -- it's cleaner and will work better if "stuff" can be reassigned. Besides, it's recommended in the Google guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Using a class (or classes) can help you organize your code.
Simplicity of form (such as through use of class attributes and methods) is important because it helps you see your algorithm, and can help you more easily unit test the parts.

IMO, these benefits far outweigh the slight loss of speed that may come with using OOP.